# While Loop not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am testing a simple linear diophantine equations code. Here is the code:

```
a = 3
b = 4
n = 67

i = 0
while True:
    if i * a <= n:
        if (n - (i * a)) % b == 0:
                yy = int((n - (i * a)) / b)
                print("{0} x {1} + {2} x {3} = {4}".format(a, i, b, yy, n))
        i = i + 1
    else:
        print("No possible solution!")
        break
```

When the code is run, it is able to find the possible x and y in this equation (which is fine). But, what I can't figure out is why is the print "No Possible solution!" is getting printed together with the answer. The else block is suppose to appear only if a solution is not possible e.g a = 3, b = 4 and n = 2.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You only have one break, so the loop can only end after printing that. Even if it takes the first branch at first, it will continue looping until it breaks.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print("No possible solution!")` is inside the else case so it will execute regardless of whether any solutions were found or not.

Here is one way to fix it where a boolean variable keeps track of whether a solution was found or not and prints the message based on the state of that variable:

```
a = 3
b = 4
n = 2

i = 0
solution_found = False
while True:
    if i * a <= n:
        if (n - (i * a)) % b == 0:
            yy = int((n - (i * a)) / b)
            print("{0} x {1} + {2} x {3} = {4}".format(a, i, b, yy, n))
            solution_found = True
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break

if not solution_found:
    print("No possible solution!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Silly me, couldn't think of this at all!

Answer (score 0):

Use flag to identify solution is available or not.

```
a = 3
b = 4
n = 67

i = 0
isSolutionAvailable=False
while True:
    if i * a <= n:
        if (n - (i * a)) % b == 0:
                yy = int((n - (i * a)) / b)
                print("{0} x {1} + {2} x {3} = {4}".format(a, i, b, yy, n))
                isSolutionAvailable=True
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break
if(not(isSolutionAvailable)):
    print("No possible solution!")
```